# Trouble generating a random animation

Tags: java, android, animation, random, int

I'm trying to generate a random animation to load for an `ImageView`. It works, but only sometimes. After three animations are picked, it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and I'm not sure why. If I catch the Exception, three animations will be picked at random, then none will load.

```
final int[] anim = { R.anim.anim_0, R.anim.anim_1, R.anim.anim_2,
            R.anim.anim_3, R.anim.anim_4, R.anim.anim_5 }; 

Random ran = new Random();

int i = ran.nextInt(6 - 1);

mAlbum.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getBaseContext(), anim[i++]));
```

Comment: Why do you have a `i++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `anim[ran.nextInt(anim.length)]` instead. This will choose a number from zero (inclusive) to the number of elements in the array (exclusive) and will prevent the exception.

```
int i = ran.nextInt(anim.length);
mAlbum.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getBaseContext(), anim[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

why the i++? i think what you would like to do is regenerate the random number and not simply increase your past result by one....

```
mAlbum.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getBaseContext(), anim[ran.nextInt(anim.length)]));
```